# Precompactness of set in $\ell_p$.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $\{a \in \ell_p : \sum_{n \ge 1} n^\alpha |a_i|^\beta \le 1\}$. We want to examine compactness of this set for different values of $\alpha, \beta$.

My attempt. First of all notice that $|a_i| \le \frac{1}{n^{\alpha / \beta}}$. We need to prove that this set is bounded and has low $\sum_{i \ge N}|a_i|^p$.

Let's start with boundary conditions: $\sum_{i \ge 1} |a_i|^p \le \sum_{i \ge 1} \dfrac{1}{n^{\alpha p / \beta}} < C$. Hence we have that $\alpha p > \beta$. The same idea works for tail bound. Hence it suppose to be $\alpha p > \beta$. But is that enough? Maybe the bound isn't tight.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is tight. For instance if $\beta=p$, then any $\alpha >0$ should work, right?